# How do I write out the month and year in which an event occurred within a web article (or any publication for that matter)?

Tags: american-english, dates

I'm aware the answer to this question may differ across writing styles, but within a web article, should I write "In June of 2020, X occurred" or "In June 2020, X occurred"? I can't find a clear answer on the internet. Does anyone know why it matters?

Thank you!

Edit: Moderators closed this question because they suggested there is another one that answers it, but I'm not asking whether:
"In June, 2020, X occurred"
or
"In June 2020, X occurred"
is correct.

I'm asking if "In June of 2020, X occurred" is correct. *Of* is the difference here.

Comment: Unless you are governed by a style sheet or manual, there are many ways to say it. Writer’s choice.

Comment: My 5th-grade teacher would call for an extra comma:  "In June, 2020, X occurred".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is “month year” or “month, year” the more common form of punctuation in print publishing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423580/is-month-year-or-month-year-the-more-common-form-of-punctuation-in-print-pu) saw's answer begins << 
Bryan Garner, [in] Garner's Modern American Usage, second edition (2003), has a useful entry on this matter:

**DATES. ... B. Month and Year.** February 2003 _is better than_ February of 2003. >> However, including the preposition is not ungrammatical, and gives a more familiar flavour ...

Comment: sometimes appropriate, but rarely desirable in dry historical accounts.